# "roll axis" using inner and outer values in Dictorionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I'm kind of new for dictionaries in python and have the following dictionary structure (I prefer to show it as simple as possible, trying to omit every key and value):

```
data_group_test = {Example: {model: {: epoch{: dataset {np.array}}}}
```

but I would like it to be

```
data_group_test = {Example: {model: {: dataset {: epoch {np.array}}}}
```

Is there a way to do this swapping between inner/outer values? It is like a np.rollaxis but with a dictionary.

Edited: All of components them are dictionaries and every dataset contains the same quantity and values of epochs. (eg. Epoch 20,40,60 are in the dataset a,b, and c)

Thanks.

Comment: Are any of those values lists or are they all dictionaries? Do you know for certain that a given dataset can only have one epoch?

Comment: @JonSG all of the values in the list are dictionaries, and per every dataset there is always the same number of epochs

Comment: just to be clear, there is a one to one correspondence between epoch a dataset right?

Comment: @JonSG yes, eg. Epoch 20,40,60 are in the 3 datasets a,b, and c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set variables to the two dictionaries and then set the to their proper place in the hierarchy. Then clean up the tree by deleting the unwanted items:

conceptually

```py
import json

data_group_tests = {
    "example1": {
        "model1": {
            "epoch1": {
                "epoch1_item": "epoch1_item",
                "dataset1": {"dataset1_item": "dataset1_item"}
            }
        }
    }
}

root = data_group_tests["example1"]["model1"]
parent = root["epoch1"]["dataset1"]
child = root["epoch1"]
parent["epoch1"] = child
root["dataset1"] = parent

del child["dataset1"]
del root["epoch1"]

print(json.dumps(data_group_tests, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thank you @JonSG This is what I was looking for